# Correlated pattern definitions and Snowflake’s MATCH_RECOGNIZE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to find out when a Customer changed for an Order and was reverted back in the following data. The Order can be assigned to several different Customer before being reverted back to the original Customer. Here is the raw data:

| ORDER_NUM | CUSTOMER | LOAD_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | aaa | 2023-02-09 04:49:41.335 |
| 111 | bbb | 2023-02-09 04:49:42.338 |
| 111 | aaa | 2023-02-09 04:49:43.278 |
| 222 | aaa | 2023-02-09 04:49:44.213 |
| 222 | bbb | 2023-02-09 04:49:45.254 |
| 333 | aaa | 2023-02-09 04:49:46.334 |
| 333 | bbb | 2023-02-09 04:49:47.101 |
| 333 | ccc | 2023-02-09 04:49:48.196 |

I developed the following [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://structured-query-language.github.io/correlated-pattern-definitions-and-MATCH_RECOGNIZE.html) query in Oracle and it works:

```
select * from order_customer
match_recognize(
    partition by order_number
    order by load_date
    one row per match
    pattern (init modified+ reversed)
    define
      init as customer_id = customer_id,
      modified as customer_id <> init.customer_id,
      reversed as customer_id = init.customer_id
);
```

But it seems like Snowflake currently doesn't support Correlated pattern definition in [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://structured-query-language.github.io/correlated-pattern-definitions-and-MATCH_RECOGNIZE.html). What is the best way to implement this in Snowflake?

Comment: It would be much easier if you provide desired output and more cases to avoid future clarifications and/or extending the sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use case could be resolved with `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
select * from order_customer
match_recognize(
    partition by order_number
    order by load_date
    one row per match
    pattern (init modified+ reversed)
    define
      init as customer_id = FIRST_VALUE(customer_id),
      modified as customer_id <> FIRST_VALUE(customer_id),
      reversed as customer_id = FIRST_VALUE(customer_id)
);
```

For input:

```
create or replace table order_customer (order_number number,
                                        customer_id varchar(80),
                                        load_date timestamp);
insert into order_customer values (111, 'aaa', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into order_customer values (111, 'bbb', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into order_customer values (111, 'aaa', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into order_customer values (222, 'aaa', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into order_customer values (222, 'bbb', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into order_customer values (333, 'aaa', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into order_customer values (333, 'bbb', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into order_customer values (333, 'ccc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Output:

[image]

---

Simplifying the entire pattern to `(init modified+ init)`:

```
select * from order_customer
match_recognize(
    partition by order_number
    order by load_date
    one row per match
    pattern (init modified+ init)
    define
      init as customer_id = FIRST_VALUE(customer_id),
      modified as customer_id <> FIRST_VALUE(customer_id)
);
```